# How to use tuple <timestamp,text> in cql where clause?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I am using tuple<timestamp, text> to store timestamp and zone information in the Cassandra database.

I want to filter data based on timestamps.

Is there any way I can use this tuple in where clause for comparison in cql?

I have tried following cql query but it is not giving me proper results

```
SELECT extid,time_created_ from d_account where time_created_>=('2021-04-06 7:09:06', '+05:30') allow filtering;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your problem? the query result is wrong or query is not executed?

Comment: query was not returning result as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer so that someone might get help in the future.

The following query worked for me and returned the expected results.

```
SELECT extid,time_created_ from d_account where time_created_ < ('2021-04-06 07:24:10.347+0000', '+05:30') allow filtering;
```